# Show that $P^2$ = $P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank, transpose

Let $P$ = $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, where A is $m \times n  $ 0f rank $n$.
This is the projection matrix, right? Every site I've been on says that this is the projection matrix such that $P^2$ = $P$, but none explain why. Is this just a property of a projection matrix that doesn't require proof?

Comment: Did you try to write out $P^2$ explicitly?

Comment: If you agree it's a projection matrix, what do you think will happen if you project twice in a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by direct computation

$$P^2 = \left(A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T\right)\left(A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T\right) = A(A^T A)^{-1}(A^TA)(A^T A)^{-1}A^T=A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T = P.$$

In fact, this is the projection matrix onto the column space of a full column rank matrix $A$.

Comment: I should have tried that first, oops. Thank you for writing it all out, though.